# sqlite select where field time

Tags: sqlite, select, filter, strftime

I have an sqlite table as follow:
[image]
I have to select the rows where 'start'< now time in order to have just the ongoing program; logically as:
if time now is 10:05 then the result should be:
[image]
How I can formulate the right select statement?
Thank u in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`strftime()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) to get the current time in the format `HH:MM` so that you can compare it to the column `start`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE start < strftime('%H:%M', 'now');
```

If you want only the last row for each `dpt`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE start < strftime('%H:%M', 'now')
GROUP BY dpt
HAVING MAX(start);
```

Comment: thank u so much.That solved my problem.

Comment: sorry for delayed check. Thank u  again so much